# World Map flat Mercator.svg with country names

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have found an awesome [World Map flat Mercator](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_Map_flat_Mercator.svg) unfortunately the ids are arbitrary. Anyone know any Flat SVG maps that have Countries names set as the ids?

Example of this is [rounded map with country ids](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/World_map_-_low_resolution.svg):

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="russia" d="M817.97,72.93l1.76,6.08l3.52,1.01l3.52-5.57l-2.01-3.8l0.75-3.29h5.28l-1.26,2.53l0.5,9.12l-7.54,18.74l0.75,4.05l-0.25,6.84l14.07,20.51l2.76,0.76l0.25-16.71l2.76-2.53l-3.02-6.58l2.51-2.79l-5.53-7.34l-3.02,0.25l-1-12.15l7.79-2.03l0.5-3.55l4.02-1.01l2.26,2.03l2.76-11.14l4.77-8.1l3.77-2.03l3.27,0.25v-3.8l-5.28-1.01l-7.29-6.08l3.52-4.05l-3.02-6.84l2.51-2.53l3.02,4.05l7.54,2.79l8.29,0.76l1.01-3.54l-4.27-4.3l4.77-6.58l-10.81-3.8l-2.76,5.57l-3.52-4.56l-19.85-6.84l-18.85,3.29l-2.76,1.52v1.52l4.02,2.03l-0.5,4.81l-7.29-3.04l-16.08,6.33l-2.76-5.82h-11.06l-5.03,5.32l-17.84-4.05l-16.33,3.29l-2.01,5.06l2.51,0.76l-0.25,3.8l-15.83,1.77l1.01,5.06l-14.58-2.53l3.52-6.58l-14.83-0.76l1.26,6.84l-4.77,2.28l-4.02-3.8l-16.33,2.79l-6.28,5.82l-0.25,3.54l-4.02,0.25l-0.5-4.05l12.82-11.14v-7.6l-8.29-2.28l-10.81,3.54l-4.52-4.56h-2.01l-2.51,5.06l2.01,2.28l-14.33,7.85l-12.31,9.37l-7.54,10.38v4.3l8.04,3.29l-4.02,3.04l-8.54-3.04l-3.52,3.04l-5.28-6.08l-1.01,2.28l5.78,18.23l1.51,0.51l4.02-2.03l2.01,1.52v3.29l-3.77-1.52l-2.26,1.77l1.51,3.29l-1.26,8.61l-7.79,0.76l-0.5-2.79l4.52-2.79l1.01-7.6l-5.03-6.58l-1.76-11.39l-8.04-1.27l-0.75,4.05l1.51,2.03l-3.27,2.79l1.26,7.6l4.77,2.03l1.01,5.57l-4.78-3.04l-12.31-2.28l-1.51,4.05l-9.8,3.54l-1.51-2.53l-12.82,7.09l-0.25,4.81l-5.03,0.76l1.51-3.54v-3.54l-5.03-1.77l-3.27,1.27l2.76,5.32l2.01,3.54v2.79l-3.77-0.76l-0.75-0.76l-3.77,4.05l2.01,3.54l-8.54-0.25l2.76,3.55l-0.75,1.52h-4.52l-3.27-2.28l-0.75-6.33l-5.28-2.03v-2.53l11.06,2.28l6.03,0.51l2.51-3.8l-2.26-4.05l-16.08-6.33l-5.55,1.38l-1.9,1.63l0.59,3.75l2.36,0.41l-0.55,5.9l7.28,17.1l-5.26,8.34l-0.36,1.88l2.67,1.88l-2.41,1.59l-1.6,0.03l0.3,7.35l2.21,3.13l0.03,3.04l2.83,0.26l4.33,1.65l4.58,6.3l0.05,1.66l-1.49,2.55l3.42-0.19l3.33,0.96l4.5,6.37l11.08,1.01l-0.48,7.58l-3.82,3.27l0.79,1.28l-3.77,4.05l-1,3.8l2.26,3.29l7.29,2.53l3.02-1.77l19.35,7.34l0.75-2.03l-4.02-3.8v-4.81l-2.51-0.76l0.5-4.05l4.02-4.81l-7.21-5.4l0.5-7.51l7.71-5.07l9.05,0.51l1.51,2.79l9.3,0.51l6.79-3.8l-3.52-3.8l0.75-7.09l17.59-8.61l13.53,6.1l4.52-4.05l13.32,12.66l10.05-1.01l3.52,3.54l9.55,1.01l6.28-8.61l8.04,3.55l4.27,0.76l4.27-3.8l-3.77-2.53l3.27-5.06l9.3,3.04l2.01,4.05l4.02,0.25l2.51-1.77l6.79-0.25l0.75,1.77l7.79,0.51l5.28-5.57l10.81,1.27l3.27-1.27l1-6.08l-3.27-7.34l3.27-2.79h10.3l9.8,11.65l12.56,7.09h3.77l0.5-3.04l4.52-2.79l0.5,16.46l-4.02,0.25v4.05l2.26,2.79l-0.42,3.62l1.67,0.69l1.01-2.53l1.51,0.51l1,1.01l4.52-1.01l4.52-13.17l0.5-16.46l-5.78-13.17l-7.29-8.86l-3.52,0.51v2.79l-8.54-3.29l3.27-7.09l2.76-18.74l11.56-3.54l5.53-3.54h6.03L805.86,96l1.51,2.53l5.28-5.57l3.02,0.25l-0.5-3.29l-4.78-1.01l3.27-11.9L817.97,72.93L817.97,72.93z"/>
```

Flat map without proper country ids:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill:#b9b9b9;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" id="path4123" d="m 997.62384,503.51361 7.83296,-0.167 3.667,2 6,1.333 2.667,2.167 5.5,0.167 1.833,2.833 4.5,1.167 2.667,2.5 1.833,0.667 2,-2.167 -2,-4.167 -2.75,-4 1,-3.5 -1.5,-0.75 -1.25,-2.5 -2.25,-0.75 2.5,-2.75 2,-5.25 0.75,-2 2,2.25 1.667,-1.583 0.333,-2.5 2,-2.667 -1.167,-2 -7.167,-6.833 -1.667,-2.833 2.5,-13.167 5.167,3.667 0.833,-2.5 -0.833,-2.333 1.5,-2 0.083,-3.25 3.083,0.417 3.833,-2.167 0.5,-1.667 3,1 -0.5,2.167 2.167,-1.5 2.333,0.167 2.667,-0.833 2.833,0.833 3.333,3.333 0.667,3.333 1.583,-2.583 1.083,0.417 2.167,1.5 2.167,0.333 2.167,-2.5 h 3.5 l 1.833,1.167 3.833,-1 1.5,2.5 2.833,1.5 2.167,-1.667 3.5,1.333 4.167,-5 -2,-1.333 -2.917,-0.25 -1.25,-2.417 -1.833,-1.167 3.833,-1.667 -0.5,-4.833 6,0.167 -2.75,-4.583 1.75,-1.583 -2.667,-1.333 1.167,-2.667 2.833,0.667 10,-1.667 3,0.333 4,-3.667 7.167,-0.667 2.5,-1.167 3.5,-3.5 3.25,1.25 3.917,0.583 1.083,3.667 1.083,1.333 -0.5,3.167 2.167,1.667 0.667,-1.667 2.583,0.5 0.75,1.5 2.333,-0.833 0.5,1 0.333,2.5 5.833,0.333 1.833,-2.333 2,-0.333 2.5,-4.667 3,-0.167 -1.5,2.667 6.417,7.833 4.75,4.5 3.75,8.25 1.083,2.417 3.333,-3.833 1.833,1 2,3.667 4,-0.167 3,-1 2.667,0.333 2.833,5.667 2.5,-0.167 2.167,3 2.333,-0.333 2.5,-1.333 1.333,2.5 -0.667,1.5 h 4.5 l 1.833,-2.25 3.833,-0.25 1.167,-2.667 2.25,0.667 2.5,-1.75 3.583,-0.583 2.333,-2 1.667,0.333 0.5,-1 2.167,2.167 5.667,-0.167 2.583,2.5 1.25,1 4,-0.333 6.667,1.667 2,-0.667 0.667,-5 -1.833,-0.833 -0.333,-3.5 1.5,-4.667 1.833,1.333 1.167,-3.5 4.333,2.25 6.167,1.75 0.833,1.5 3.75,0.25 -0.583,3.25 1.667,3.333 3.917,1.167 2.417,-0.333 1.833,-1.167 5.333,0.667 1.167,0.833 3.333,-0.167 3.417,3.167 4.25,1.833 4.5,0.917 5.5,1 4.667,-1.25 4.583,-2 1.75,-2.25 1,-2 3.5,-0.917 2.25,0.167 1.75,2.5 0.5,1.333 2.833,-0.667 3.417,1.083 4.417,2.583 2.083,-2.333 1.75,-1.75 1.833,-0.083 -0.083,-2.917 1.917,-4.417 3,-3.5 1.167,-4.333 -1.833,-2.25 -1,-0.5 2.667,-3.75 4.083,-0.5 4.083,-0.167 3.667,-1.083 3.5,2 3.833,1.917 0.5,-1 3.167,2.833 3.75,9.25 3.417,7.25 v 2.833 l 1.333,1.333 6.833,1.167 3.5,5.167 1.167,-0.333 -0.5,2.167 1.5,1.917 v 2.417 l 3.25,1.333 4.75,-1.75 6.25,-1.75 4.583,-1.333 -1.333,2.667 -0.5,3 -1.5,1.667 -0.5,3.5 -2.333,4.333 -1.333,3.833 -1.5,1.5 0.167,1.667 -4.5,-1.583 -1.667,0.583 -1.333,1.917 -1.75,0.25 1.25,5 -0.667,4 -0.167,1.5 -3.333,2.083 1.583,1.667 0.458,-1.5 1.5,0.25 1.625,-0.875 0.75,-2.125 0.25,-1.375 0.5,-0.875 0.375,2.25 1.625,-1 0.75,1.25 2.375,1 1.875,0.75 2.25,-1.5 2,-0.625 3,-2.375 1.625,-2.375 2.375,-3.125 h 1 c 0,0 1.5,-4.25 1.875,-4.5 0.375,-0.25 3.75,-2.375 3.75,-2.375 l 2.625,-5 1.5,-3 1.125,-2.875 1.25,-0.875 0.75,-2.375 2,-2.375 1.625,-2.25 1.5,-2 -0.375,-3.625 1.25,-1.125 -0.125,-3.25 -0.25,-3.25 1.125,-4.75 0.25,-3 1.875,-2 0.875,-1.75 1.125,-0.125 0.25,2.75 1.75,2.875 -0.125,4.25 -0.125,4.375 0.125,5.375 -1.875,4.375 1.25,0.5 0.75,3.625 -0.875,2.25 0.125,4.125 -1.125,2 0.5,3.875 1.5,1.75 0.25,-2.375 0.25,-2.125 1.875,-1.375 c 0,0 1.75,1 2,1.375 0.25,0.375 1.75,2.25 1.75,2.25 l 0.125,-2.125 -2,-3.125 -0.875,-2.125 -2.5,-2 0.625,-3 1,-3.125 0.25,-2.625 2.625,-1.875 h 2.75 l 2.625,3.5 1.375,-0.625 -1.75,-2.125 -2,-3.375 -1.625,-4.75 -0.875,-4.125 -0.625,-3.25 -0.25,-2.375 -1.75,-2.5 0.625,-2.625 0.875,0.75 -0.5,-5.75 -0.625,-3.375 -0.75,-1.875 0.375,-1.125 -0.875,-2.25 -1.375,0.5 -1.75,0.125 2.125,2 -0.125,2.125 -2,1 -1.875,0.875 0.75,2.25 0.5,1.625 -0.75,2.375 -0.375,1.5 -0.125,1.125 h -1.375 l -0.625,-1.5 1.25,-0.125 -0.75,-2.625 -0.75,-1 0.75,-0.875 0.125,-1.75 -1.75,-1.625 -1.875,-1.125 -0.875,-1.375 -2.25,-1.875 -0.375,-0.875 -1.75,0.875 -2.625,-1.375 0.125,2.875 -0.375,2.5 -1.375,-0.25 0.5,-2.625 -1.875,1.25 -0.875,1.75 h -2.5 l 1.875,-2.125 -0.75,-1 0.875,-2 h -2.5 l -1.125,2.125 -0.25,-1.875 0.25,-2.125 -1.625,-1.125 -3.125,0.75 -2,-1.25 0.75,-2.375 2.5,-1.5 2.375,-2 2.625,-2.875 2.875,-2.125 2,-3.75 3.625,-4.125 2.5,-2.125 v -3 h 2.125 l 1.875,-4 3.875,-3 3.125,-2.875 4.25,-0.375 5.875,-0.25 2.5,-1.5 1.875,-0.5 0.875,0.75 1.5,-0.25 1.375,-1.5 2.5,0.875 1.625,0.625 2.375,-0.625 1.75,0.625 1,0.625 2.125,-0.5 -0.875,-1.25 1.125,-1 0.25,-2.375 2.625,0.75 3.625,1.833 3.5,0.167 1.833,1 c 0,0 3.5,1.5 3,1.5 -0.5,0 -5.166,0 -5.166,0 l -0.334,2 2.5,1.167 2.834,-1.5 2.5,0.5 2,-2.167 2.833,1.5 1.5,-2.167 4,0.5 -2.667,-3 h -2.166 l -0.167,-4.167 1.167,1.167 1.666,-4.667 3.334,-2.167 1.833,-3 3.167,-2 -0.334,-2.833 6.834,-2 3.833,-0.833 0.833,1.167 3.167,-1.333 -0.833,4.333 -1,1.5 0.333,3.167 2.167,-1 -1.167,3.333 2.833,-1.667 2.834,-2.333 4.166,-3.667 2,-1.667 1.167,1 0.167,-3.5 0.166,-4.5 2.167,-1.5 4.667,-1 2.333,2.5 -4.333,0.833 -0.667,4.167 -1.167,2.833 0.167,2.5 -1,1.833 -0.5,2.833 -2.667,0.167 -3.5,2.167 -0.166,2.5 -6.5,5.833 -2.834,4 -4,4.833 -3.333,4.5 -2.667,0.667 -2.5,-0.333 v 3.167 l -1.333,3 -3.833,4 -0.667,8.833 v 6.167 l 1,6.5 2,7.667 0.333,4.667 0.667,4.833 1,2 -1.833,1.5 -2.167,1 -2.833,2.167 -0.834,2 v 2 l -1.166,1.833 -1.5,2.167 -2,2.333 -1.334,3.333 -2.333,1.5 -1,2.5 -1.333,2.5 -2.5,1.167 -1.834,2.333 -3.667,2.833 -3,0.833 -2.167,2.833 -2.5,2 h -2.167 l -2.333,-0.5 -1.333,2.333 -3.5,2.667 -1,1.333 -1.667,-0.333 -1.833,2 -0.5,1.833 1.167,-1 2.167,-1.167 0.667,-0.667 2,-1.667 v 1.833 l 2.333,-2.167 2,-1.667 2,-1.333 2.333,-0.833 2,-1.833 0.833,1 1.333,-2 2.333,-1.5 0.5,-1.167 4.833,-3.167 1.5,-0.167 1.5,-1.833 0.5,-1 1.5,-2.5 1.666,-0.833 -0.166,-1.5 0.833,-0.833 0.667,-0.833 1.333,-2 0.667,-1.5 2,-0.667 -0.334,-1.167 1.667,-1.5 1.333,-1.167 -0.666,-1 1,-2.833 2.833,-0.667 1,-2.833 0.833,-0.833 1.167,-1.333 1.5,-1 2.333,-1.667 1.5,-1.667 1.5,-1.833 2.334,-4.833 -0.5,-3.667 v -1 h 2.333 l 2.167,-1.167 2.166,0.833 -0.333,-4.5 -0.333,-1.667 3.5,-4.333 2.333,-0.167 1.333,0.5 2.334,-1.833 -1,-3 -0.667,-3 1.333,-3.333 0.167,-2 3.167,-1.667 -1,3.333 2,1.167 1.5,-3 -1,-1.833 v -2 h -2.167 l 1,-4.833 1,-1.833 -2.667,-1.833 -2.166,1.167 0.333,-3.833 2.167,-3.667 1.333,-3.333 0.833,-2.833 0.834,-3 1.166,-2.167 2.834,-1.667 c 0,0 -0.5,1.833 0,1.333 0.5,-0.5 2.666,-1.5 2.666,-1.5 l 0.167,2.333 4.167,-3.5 2.166,-0.833 -0.666,4.5 1.333,-0.5 3.5,-4.167 3.667,-1 3.833,-0.667 3,2.167 2.333,3.333 3.167,-4.667 3.667,-3 7.166,-7.333 4.667,-3.333 6.5,-2.333 5.167,-3.333 6.5,1 2.166,2.167 1,-3.833 -0.666,-3.833 -2.5,-4.5 -2,-2.333 0.833,-4.833 -0.333,-1.333 -4.667,-0.667 0.167,-4 4.833,1 2.667,-0.833 3.333,-2 3.833,-4.167 -2.166,-4.5 -0.667,-2.667 3.667,-0.833 2.5,-1.167 -0.834,3 1.5,4.167 -2,1.167 5.167,0.333 2.5,-1.167 3.167,1.5 2.5,3.833 -0.834,0.833 3.834,2.5 2.833,-0.5 1.5,2.833 1.667,2.667 3.666,-1 v -3.333 l 2.5,-2.833 1.667,-3.333 -2.333,-2.833 5.333,1.667 1.167,-2 2,-2 3.833,-2.5 -3.667,-3.167 -4.833,-4.333 -3.667,-2.5 -2.5,0.333 -3.166,-2.333 h -3 l 0.666,5.167 -1.5,-2 -1.166,-4 -0.667,-4.5 -3.5,-2.167 0.5,2.333 -3.167,-2.667 0.167,-2 -4,-2.333 -6.167,-4.167 -0.833,-3 -5.667,-3 -4.333,-4.333 -5.333,-1.333 -5,-3.5 -2.5,-2.5 -8.167,0.5 h -6 l -9,-2 -0.334,4.333 -1.333,1.667 3.833,3.333 -0.666,3.667 -4.834,2.333 -3,-2.667 -2.166,-1 -0.334,-4.167 -2.333,-2.5 3,1.333 2.667,-1 -0.167,-2.833 -4.833,-1.167 v 2.167 l -1.667,1.667 -3,1.333 -0.667,2.833 -1.5,-2 -3.833,-0.333 -4.833,-0.167 -3.667,-3.167 -2.5,1.333 -4,0.333 -2.5,2 -3,-1.167 -4.167,-2.5 -2.666,-0.833 1.5,-3 0.5,-2.833 -1.667,-4.167 -2.667,-3.833 -5.666,-1 -6.334,0.333 -10.166,0.5 -3.667,0.167 -2.833,0.167 -0.834,-2.5 -0.666,-3.833 -3.834,0.167 -2.833,-2.667 -2.333,-1.667 -3.833,-0.333 1.833,-1.667 3.833,0.333 -2.167,-4.5 -5.667,-2.667 -5.333,0.333 -2.5,5.167 -3.333,3.333 -3.333,1.333 -0.333,-2.667 1.667,-2.167 3,-3.667 -0.333,5 3.167,-6.833 -3.667,1 -3.167,1 -3.667,-1 0.333,-3 5.5,0.833 3,-0.667 -4.333,-1.667 -4.833,-0.833 -6.167,-1.5 -4.333,-0.167 -3.5,-1.167 -0.333,3.833 -1.667,2 h -4.333 l -2.167,2.833 h 4.5 l -2.833,3.667 3,6.167 -4.5,0.833 -2,-1.833 -3.333,2.5 -2.333,-2.333 h -3.167 l -5.667,-1.167 -4,4.5 -3.667,-2.5 -3.833,-5.167 -3.333,8.167 -0.667,4.5 -2.333,2.167 -3.5,-3.167 -5.167,-3.5 -0.667,-4.5 -0.667,-4.333 1.333,-4 0.833,-7 -0.5,-5 -5.5,-6.833 -6.5,0.333 -6.833,-3.167 -7,-1.667 -1,6 0.667,5.5 -3.667,0.5 -9.333,-0.833 -4.5,-1.167 -2.667,0.833 -1.5,-4.333 2.5,-1 -6.667,-1.667 -9,-1.833 -4.333,1.833 -4.333,0.167 -1,-4.833 -1.333,-1.5 -1.5,4.167 -4.167,-1.667 -0.333,-3.333 -3.833,1.833 -3.167,-0.333 -0.667,4.833 3.167,1 -6,4.167 -8,1 -4.167,1.5 1.333,-3.833 6,-4.833 2.333,-0.833 4.333,-5.167 3.333,-4.833 7,-4.5 2.833,1.833 -4.333,3.333 2.667,3.833 3.5,-1.167 3,-4.5 -4,-1.167 -3.5,-2.833 2.333,-2.667 4,-3.333 2,-4.333 1,-3 -2.833,-2.667 2.333,-1.333 0.167,-3.333 -2.333,-4.167 -0.667,-2.833 -2.667,1.833 -1.5,-6.333 -5.667,-3 -7.833,-0.833 -5.833,1.167 -1.167,2.667 h -7.167 l 5.5,-5.5 1.5,-3.667 -8.167,-1.333 -4.333,0.833 4.167,-5.5 2.5,-3.167 -5.333,-2 -5.5,-1 -7.333,4.833 -5.333,9.5 1.5,3.5 1.5,4.667 -5.833,-0.667 h -4.5 l 3,4.5 -4.333,0.333 -6.5,3.333 -6,2 2.167,-5.167 -7,2 c 0,0 -9.333,0.667 -8.833,1 0.5,0.333 5.5,2.5 5.5,2.5 l -13,4.333 -8.5,4.667 -5,4.333 -3.167,-0.167 -0.833,4.167 -4,1.833 3.333,5.167 c 0,0 -3.333,2 -2.833,2.667 0.5,0.667 7,6.167 7,6.167 l -4.167,2 -6,0.833 -6.333,-0.333 -7,1.667 -5.167,1.667 -2,5.5 2.5,6.333 -0.667,3.667 4.667,3.833 2,1.333 1.667,3.667 2.5,1.833 -0.333,4.833 0.333,7.833 -2.167,-0.833 -2,1.167 v -5.833 l 2.667,-3.667 0.167,-3 -2.833,-0.667 -2.167,1 -4,-3.5 -5.833,-5.167 -4.5,-1 -4,2.833 1.833,2.833 -2.333,1.667 -3.167,-2.5 -3.333,1.833 4.667,7.167 5.667,1.667 -1.333,4 -4.167,-2.833 -4,-0.5 -5,-2.333 1,-6.333 c 0,0 0.333,-5.167 0.333,-5.667 0,-0.5 0,-6.667 0,-6.667 l -2.667,-2.833 v 2.833 l 0.667,4 -1.667,4.667 -6,3.5 -0.833,5.5 4.833,7.333 0.667,5 -2.667,6 -0.167,6.667 2,6 5.833,-2.167 h 5.167 l 4,4.5 0.833,6 1,2.167 -2.167,3.167 2.167,1.667 1.833,1.667 -2.667,0.833 -3.5,-2.167 1.333,-5.333 -1.167,-4 -2.667,-5 -8.5,3 -1.167,5.167 3.333,5.5 -3.5,3.333 -1.5,2.833 -2.167,4 -4.667,3.5 0.167,3.667 -4.667,-1.833 -5,-0.333 3.333,-2.333 3.5,-2 3.167,-4.833 0.833,-3.5 2.833,-2.167 0.167,-5.167 2.333,-4.333 -5.167,-5 -0.167,-7 1.167,-6 -1.667,-4.167 2.333,-0.833 -0.5,-9 -3.333,-5 -0.5,-2.833 1.833,-7.833 1,-5.667 -0.833,-3.167 -4.833,-1.333 -4.5,0.167 1.167,-2.833 4.667,-0.833 -2.167,-3.167 -2.667,-1.667 -3.167,3.667 2.333,2.5 -1.167,2.5 -2.333,-0.833 -1.5,2.667 -0.833,3.333 -1.333,5.333 -1,4.833 -2.333,5 -4.833,4 1.167,2.5 -3,1.833 1.167,1.833 2.333,-1 v 3.333 3.667 l 0.5,2.667 -2.667,1.833 0.833,4.5 1.667,-1.5 3,2.167 0.667,-0.5 v 4 l 2.5,4 1.333,0.167 -0.833,4.333 -1.667,3.833 -2.167,-3.167 -2.333,-3.167 c 0,0 -1.5,-2.5 -2,-2.5 -0.5,0 -3.833,-0.667 -3.833,-0.667 l -5,-3.167 -3.833,-3.833 -4,-1.833 -5,-1.167 -4.5,-0.167 -2.167,0.667 -1.333,-4.167 -6.167,-5 -0.333,3 1.167,3.667 2.833,2.667 3.5,0.5 v 1.333 l 0.667,3.333 1.833,3.5 -0.5,3.5 -3.333,0.833 -0.5,3.833 -2.833,-0.5 v -4.833 l -1.333,-2.667 -3.5,2.667 -3.5,1 -0.167,2 -4,-0.5 -4.5,0.833 -2,4.167 -4.167,-0.5 c 0,0 -4.833,-0.667 -3,-1 1.833,-0.333 4.167,-2.5 4.167,-2.5 v -3.667 l -4.833,-0.167 -3.333,2 0.5,3.833 -3.833,-1.833 -3.833,3.333 -8.833,3.833 -2.333,3.5 -2,5.667 -2.833,2.5 -5.833,-1.667 -1.833,-4.167 0.667,-4.167 2.667,-0.333 2.833,-1.167 -0.833,-2.667 -1.5,-1.833 -1.833,-2.667 -5.667,-0.167 -5.667,-2 3.833,4.167 0.833,3.167 -0.833,4.333 -1.5,3.333 2.333,2.833 1.333,2.833 -0.833,5 0.333,5.667 -3.833,-4.5 -4.333,-1.833 -1.667,2.333 -4.167,3.167 -4.49996,2.833 c 0,0 -1.167,2 -0.833,2.5 0.334,0.5 2.33296,5.833 2.33296,5.833 l 2.167,3.167 -2.5,0.667 -4.49996,-2 -5.333,-1.333 -4.333,-3.167 c 0,0 -3.167,3.333 -2.667,3.667 0.5,0.334 4.167,4.833 4.167,4.833 l 3,-1 1.167,4.833 -2.5,0.167 -4.833,-0.333 -4.167,-3.667 -3,-1.833 -2,-4.667 -0.167,-4.5 0.667,-2.333 0.333,-3.167 -3.167,-3 -2.833,-3 -2.5,-2.833 -2.5,0.333 v -3 l 0.167,-2.333 3.5,1.167 1.333,2.5 4,1.667 3.833,1.667 6.167,2.167 3.5,1.833 6.333,1.333 4.5,-2.5 3.83296,-3.167 3.667,-5.333 -1,-3.167 -1.5,-4 -4.99996,-4.167 -5,-2.833 -5.167,-5.333 -4.667,-4.167 -6.667,-2.833 -5.5,-0.167 -3.833,-1.167 -2.667,-3 -3.333,-0.667 -1.833,1.833 -3.333,-0.667 -1,2 -2.833,1.667 -1,3.333 -1.5,-0.167 -1.333,2.833 v 2.167 l 1.5,3.333 3.833,4 1.167,3.5 1.167,0.667 -4.667,7.667 4.667,13.167 -0.833,1 -0.333,3.833 0.333,3.833 1.333,2.167 0.333,3.5 1.5,2.333 -2.167,3.333 2,3.167 2.5,1 0.667,3 1.167,1 -0.667,2.5 -3.167,3 -3,3 -2.333,4 -2,3.667 -3.667,3 -2.333,3.167 3.333,-1.167 0.333,1.833 3.167,2.333 1.667,-0.167 2.167,2.5 -3.833,-0.167 -1.667,0.167 -3,1.667 -1.333,1.833 0.333,2.667 -2.833,2.833 2,5.667 1.667,1.833 0.833,3.167 0.167,5 -0.167,3.333 0.667,1.833 6.167,0.667 0.833,1.833 3.5,-0.5 1.333,6.333 1.5,5 2.333,2.333 0.167,2 2.333,2 -1.167,3.167 -3.333,-0.167 0.667,2.667 0.833,3.833 2.833,-0.5 2.5,-0.167 h 3.167 l 2,2.667 0.667,5 3,0.167 1.5,4 0.667,1.667 3.5,-0.333 2.833,1.167 2.5,-1.5 1.5,2 2.333,1 2.333,1.833 1.167,-0.167 1,1.333 2.66696,0.167 -0.833,3 -0.49996,1.667 1.66696,3.333 -1.66696,2.667 -2.667,0.167 -1.833,1.833 -2.5,1.5 0.833,2 h 3.667 l -4,2.667 -3.667,0.667 3.167,3.833 -2.5,0.333 -2.167,2.833 -2.167,1 -1,1 2.667,1.5 1.5,2.333 5.333,2.167 c 0,0 1.333,0.5 1.833,0.833 0.5,0.333 1.501,3.008 1.501,3.008 z"/>
```

**QUESTION**
Where can I find flat map with country ids on the paths.  Or how can I merge these 2 maps to get a visually flat map with country ids?

Comment: The file you linked doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has two with ID set to a country abbreviation and also has a title tag that has the country's name http://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=world Free for non-commercial use

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the id="undesired countryname"

or if no id to edit, just add an id string.